# Powershell - GCI from remote machine files

Tags: powershell

Getting cannot find path when using the script below. It looks to be from the variable but I am not sure how to add that to the second line.

```
$PCname = Read-Host "Enter Name of Remote Machine"
cd $("'\\'$PCname'\c$\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther'")
Get-ChildItem CompatData*.xml | Select-String 'BlockMigration="True"'
```

If I am on the local machine, it will scrape those files and give me the out-put I need, just trying to get this to work on remote machine with a prompt to enter the machine name at the start of the script.

Comment: `$WINDOWS` is treated as a variable in your code. change the `cd` line to: ``Set-Location $("\\$PCname\c$\`$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther")`` (the backtick before `$WINDOWS` escapes it)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Perfect, thank you! I didn't even think about the $Windows being treated as a variable.

Comment: Also just noted my previous comment has `$( )` which is not needed at all, you can remove that too.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `$WINDOWS` is being treated as a variable in the expandable string (`"..."`), to solve this you can escape it with a backtick `` ` `` so it is treated as literal. See [**Handling special characters**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.4#handling-special-characters) for more info.

In addition, the [subexpression operator `$(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#subexpression-operator--) is not needed at all.

```
cd "\\$PCname\c$\`$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther"
```